# ¿Cómo colorear una fila usando Javascript y que se vaya guardando en memoria?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Supongamos que tengo esta tabla, hecha usando DataTables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a esa misma tabla le quiero ir coloreando las filas, a manera de resalte, a fin de poder ver qué filas serían por así decirlo las más relevantes y que éstas coloraciones se vayan guardando de manera tal que estos resaltes sean accesibles para cualquier dispositivo que haga consulta de dicha información. No sé si me explico.

Para este caso uso de ejemplo DataTables, pero es que ando con un proyecto en mente que quiero hacer y que implica ir coloreando las filas de la tabla, que a su vez esos resaltes se vayan guardando en algún archivo en el disco duro o base de datos,  para que otros usuarios puedan ver dichos resaltes. Algo parecido a lo que pasa cuando resaltas algo en un archivo de Excel, pero llevado a la web y preferiblemente usando Javascript.

El código aún lo estoy madurando en mi mente, no tengo nada hecho, pero me gustaría saber si es posible usar Javascript con JQuery para ejecutar este tipo de efectos y con qué código podría partir para ir probando hasta dar con el resultado.

Me encantaría oír sugerencias o respuestas. De antemano, muchas gracias a todos y buen día.

Comment: Como sabes las preguntas basadas en opiniones o recomendaciones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 2):

En tu lugar yo usaría la base de datos donde crearía estatus de prioridad. Por ejemplo, marcar dos prioridades "0 y 1" . Y en el HTML colorearía la fila.

```
"Si la fila tiene una prioridad = 1 
entonces background-color=#ffc300 "
```

En tu consulta a la base de datos añadirías esto en tu while

```
        }
    $prioridades=$row['prioridad'];
    switch($prioridades){
        case '0':
        $prioridades_css="background-color:#ffffff";
            break;
            case '1':
            $prioridades_css="background-color:#ffc300";
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Es relativamente sencillo el código a implementar, pero com te responde `Naerelis` debes ir revisando como guardarlo en la `DB` pues como entiendo piensas compartir esta información.

En si solo agrega un id a cada `tr` que vayas generando por linea de información, de esta forma puedes *colorearlo* en css

```css
#color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="color">
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Como puedes ver se colorea la fila con el id `color`

Ahora bien si posteriormente lo que vas a tener que hacer por `javascript` es cambiar la presentación por algún `id` especifico.

```js
function changeColor(){
  var x = document.getElementById("color");
  x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="color">
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="changeColor()">cambiar color</button>
```

Ahora bien si lo que buscas es en `JQuery` puedes cambiar la función a :

```javascript
function changeColor(){
  var x = $("#color");
  x.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //o agregar estilos usando jQuery
}
```